# SQL Server : search for multibyte spaces

Tags: sql-server

As part of a migration exercise, we are finding issues where the migrated data is not returning what it should unicode characters in it which seem to be non standard spaces.

[image]

Does anyone have a T-SQL script where I can search for unicode non standard spaces?

The affected column is defined as `varchar(4000)`.

Ive tried other scripts looking for Non ASCII and Unicode characters in stack overflow and its not returning non standard spaces
Also tried looking for Char(9),Char(10),char(13)

Comment: What exact character code is it? Can you [edit] and copy/paste *exactly* into your post, without pasting it anywhere else first.

Comment: If it's defined as **varchar** - it will **NOT** be able to store Unicode characters. For Unicode, you **must use** `nvarchar(n)` ..,...

Comment: What's the `collation` of the `varchar(4000)` column? On Windows with the default code page 1252 the `Â` character is octet `0xC2` which indicates this is probably UTF-8 encoded data. If you cast the stored value as `varbinary(max)` what does it look like? If I were a gambler these are probably `0xC2 0xA0` sequences representing the U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE character.

Comment: I think the spaces are coming back as A0 eg A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A